# WinstonJS is not logging data

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

First take a look into my current WinstonJS config:

```
const appRoot = require('app-root-path');
const winston = require('winston');
const path = require('path')
require('winston-daily-rotate-file');

const levels = {
    levels: {
        product: 1,
        error: 1,
        warn: 3,
        info: 4,
        debug: 5
    },
    colors: {
        product: 'magenta',
        error: 'red',
        warning: 'yellow',
        info: 'green',
        debug: 'blue',
    }
}

let getLabel = function(callingModule){
    //To support files which don't have an module
    if(typeof callingModule == 'string'){
        return callingModule;
    }
    let parts = callingModule.filename.split(path.sep);
    return path.join(parts[parts.length -2], parts.pop());
}

const errorFilter = winston.format( (info, opts) => {
    return info.level == 'error' ? info : false;
})

const productFilter = winston.format( (info, opts) => {
    return info.level == 'product' ? info : false
})

module.exports = function(callingModule){
    const logger = winston.createLogger({
        levels: levels.levels,
        format: winston.format.combine(
            winston.format.colorize(),
            winston.format.timestamp({
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
            }),
            winston.format.label({label: getLabel(callingModule)}),
            winston.format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}] [${info.level}] [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`)
        ),
        transports: [
            new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
                name: "Error logs",
                filename: `${appRoot}/logs/error-%DATE%.log`,
                level: 'error', 
                label: getLabel(callingModule),
                datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                maxSize: '20m',
                maxFiles: '14d',
                format: winston.format.combine(
                    errorFilter(),
                    winston.format.colorize(),
                    winston.format.timestamp({
                        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                    }),
                    winston.format.label({label: getLabel(callingModule)}),
                    winston.format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}] [${info.level}] [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`)
                ),
            }),
            new winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
                name: "Product logs",
                filename: `${appRoot}/logs/product-%DATE%.log`,
                level: 'product',
                label: getLabel(callingModule),
                datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                maxSize: '20m',
                maxFiles: '14d',
                format: winston.format.combine(
                    productFilter(),
                    winston.format.colorize(),
                    winston.format.timestamp({
                        format: 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss'
                    }),
                    winston.format.label({label: getLabel(callingModule)}),
                    winston.format.printf(info => `[${info.timestamp}] [${info.level}] [${info.label}]: ${info.message}`)
                ),
            })
        ]
    })
    winston.addColors(levels.colors);

    let env = process.env.NODE_ENV;

    if (env !== 'production'){
        logger.add(new winston.transports.Console({
            name: "Debug logs",
            level: 'debug',
            label: getLabel(callingModule),
            prettyPrint: function ( object ){
                return JSON.stringify(object);
            }
        }))
    }
    else if (env !== 'development') {
        logger.add(winston.transports.DailyRotateFile({
            name: "Combined logs",
            filename: `${appRoot}/logs/combined-%DATE%.log`,
            level: 'error', 
            datePattern: 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH',
            maxSize: '20m',
            maxFiles: '14d'
        }))
    }

    logger.stream = {
        write: (message, encoding) => {
            logger.info(message);
        }
    }

    return logger;
}
```

This works fine, I can log on multiple levels, some levels will be written to files, depending in which environment the process is running.

However, I can't log data such as objects, arrays and even strings to my console (and probably also to the files). Example:

```
var dates = JSON.parse(req.query.dates);
console.debug("DATES", dates)
```

It's only printing "DATES".

I tried to reconfigure my formats to printing the data, but I can't get it to work.

I tried to add json:true/false, winston.format.flat(), winstom.format.json(), ${JSON.stringify(info.message)} in the configs but there is result or difference.
How can I change this config to log the data in my console (and files)?

We are changing from the default console() to winston, so the data which we are logging is correct and it was working before the change. Only changed .log() to debug().